# Memory mapped file does not free Resources after Application ends

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, nio, memory-mapped-files

I read about 7gb of XML files (~15kb each) with Java NIO. And transform them later with JAXB.
After processing all files (~12min) and closing the application properly I am curious about the ~16GB memory consumption that my Windows 10 machine shows up.

RamMap (Sysinternals) shows, that the Mapped File consumes the majority. In fact my systems seem to hold all (?) processed files in memory. But this memory usage is listed under any process that the Windows Resource-Monitor can show me.

However, if I restart my application (via Eclipse) I can see, that my Collections are still at the same Object-Adress. So running the application a second time will change the bottleneck from hdd to cpu.

The memory is only freed when I restart my system. Logout won't do it.
Since I want to benchmark different ways to do IO with Java on my machine this is disturbing.

My pipeline processes one folder complete before starting with the next one.

1. `getAllFolders` to collect the folders (~300) that I want to process
2. `getAllFilesInFolder` to collect all files (~2k á 15kb) beneath it (recursive)
3. `unmarshal` all files (~2k) gathered by `getAllFilesInFolder` in parallel stream
4. transform a `List<MyXml>` into a single `MyXml`
5. `marshal` the `MyXml`
6. Start with next Folder

The following methods handles the creation of `List<Path>` that is used for unmarshalling.

```
// Method returns all Folders inside the entryPath
public List<Path> getAllFolders(Path entryPath) {
    List<Path> folderList = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<Path>());
    try (DirectoryStream<Path> directoryStream = Files.newDirectoryStream(entryPath)) {
        for (Path path : directoryStream) {
            if (Files.isDirectory(path)) {
                folderList.add(path);
            }
        }
    }
    return folderList;
}

// Method returns all regular Files inside the path
public List<Path> getAllFilesInFolder(Path path){
    try (Stream<Path> files = Files.walk(path).filter(Files::isRegularFile)) {
        return files.collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
    return null;
}
```

Running these together alone takes about 2 minutes and seems not to be the reason for the big mmap file.

The root course seems to be in the marshalling/unmarshalling:

```
public class XmlMarshaller {
    private JAXBContext jaxbContext;
    private XmlMarshaller() {
        jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(MyXml.class);
    }

    private static class LazyHolder {
        private static final XmlMarshaller INSTANCE = new XmlMarshaller();
    }

    public static XmlMarshaller getInstance() {
        return LazyHolder.INSTANCE;
    }

    public void marshal(MyXml xml, Path output) {
        try (OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(Files.newOutputStream(output), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
            Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
            marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_ENCODING, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString());
            marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
            marshaller.marshal(xml, osw);
        }
    }

    public MyXml unmarshal(Path file) {
        MyXml xml = null;
        try (InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(Files.newInputStream(file), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
            Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
            xml = (MyXml) unmarshaller
                    .unmarshal(isr);
        } 
        return xml;
    }
}
```

I removed the `catch(){...}` statements for better readability.

Am I handling the input/output streams correct? May I have a resource leak? Or does Windows 10 optimizes here?

Comment: How much total memory does your system have?  If you run your program over and over again, will you eventually run out of system memory?